# How to normalize phone number in the column in SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in the SQL database with a phone number column which contains a lot of numbers. The numbers look like those:

`350-564-3210`
`350.564.3210`
`(350) 564-3210`

These numbers are not normalized. I want to normalize with format like this:

`+13505643210`

It includes +1 as prefix for country code.

Comment: use a replace function. Replace '.', '-', ' ', '(', ')' with ''. and prepend +1 to it. Do some diging on this

Comment: Be careful about trying to automate this. If "not normalized" means "they are all ten-digit US phone numbers with no country codes, but with varying punctuation," removing non-numeric characters and prepending +1 would work (note that none of the solutions offered here so far actually do this; look into regex replace unless you're absolutely certain of the subset of characters you need to remove). For any other conditions, none of these things will help you; phone numbers are notoriously difficult to normalize.

Comment: @kungphu country prefix normalization is always 00, so I use opinion as +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all show us any query you did,
as  far as i am concerned what do you mean by normalization?

You need a function which does-
replace your special characters and then append +1 to left of string

You can replace and concat  like this

```
select concat('+1',replace('350-564-3210','-',''))
```

But this for one phone number you will need to make a generalize function

But still check this-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3de17b0/10

Comment: Isn't possible to select ALL numbers from the column before to replace?

Comment: See @fa06 answer, what's performance difference between `replace()` with multiple `replace();` inside and `REGEXP_REPLACE()` ?

Comment: @Ivan its regular expression replace-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: yes may be not diiference ,but its quite usefull instead of using multiple replace functions .But it is only available for mysql 8.0+

Comment: Most sites use mySql 5.6+ including wordpress site, so your answer seems useful after all

Answer (score 1):

Store special characters in an array . Do a string replace and concatenate +1.
Try the following

```
$string = "350-564.3210";
$arrayString = array('-', '.', ')', '(', ' ');
$result = str_replace($arrayString, '', $string);
print_r('+1'.$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with REGEXP_REPLACE()

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=008a413330465bdf7581f428df822f0c)

```
SELECT concat('+1',REGEXP_REPLACE('(350).564.3210','[-.()]','',1,0))
```

Comment: Since I don't want to post an answer here (I doubt the reality of this situation is simple enough for this approach), why are you not just replacing all non-numeric digits? Either `[^\d]+` or whatever format PHP's regex engine supports would be a lot more appropriate here.

Comment: yes, that could an another option definitely @kungphu

Comment: See @Kedar Limaye answer, what's performance difference between `replace()` with multiple `replace();` inside and `REGEXP_REPLACE()` ?